# Django: Define a template context processor in all templates without creating a new view

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to get an environment variable (ex: Mixpanel_Token) in all my templates, and **without creating a new view in Django**.

From what I read on SO, I should use a Template Context Processor.

The context_processor is defined in context_processors.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings
def settings_mixpanel(request):
    ctx = {
        "MIXPANEL_TOKEN": settings.MIXPANEL_TOKEN,
    }
    return ctx
```

In my settings.py file:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
'utils.context_processors.settings_mixpanel',
)
```

The issue I encounter is how to define `MIXPANEL_TOKEN` as a context variable in all my templates, given that all my views are already created in Django.

I **don't want** to recreate a view like the below one, using `render_to_response` function:

```
    def index(request):
    return render_to_response("index.html", {},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: What do you wanna mean by "I don't want" to recreate a view ? Your  template will probably be rendered in the context of a view.

Comment: Templates are handled by views. This is as unavoidable as gravity is. And now on every template you render with some view, MIXPANEL_TOKEN will be there, without you passing it explicitly every time. That's what context processors do.

Comment: 1. I don't want to add a RequestContext to all the views I've created.

Comment: ... what? What does a virtual environment have to do with anything?

Comment: Your question and generally the information you give us does not make any sense.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do anything special. As long as your template is rendered with `RequestContext`, you'll be able to access your variable with `{{ MIXPANEL_TOKEN }}`.

Comment: And if it isn't, then there's simply no avoiding doing a one-liner on all the views. RTFD on Django's template language next time https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy and straightforward: the context processors are called by RequestContext(...). If you do not use RequestContext(...), the context processors will not be used and will therefore not be of any value. You do not necessarily need to use render_to_response, but RequestContext is a must. Like it or not, that is how Django works. But from my personal view, changing your existing views to use RequestContext is not really a big thing, is it?

Answer (score 0):

since Django 1.8 registring of custom context processor for templates happens via: `TEMPLATES-> OPTIONS -> context_processors` see here for reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/upgrading/#the-templates-settings